# React-native, Parse-react and Redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux, parse-server

I am wondering if someone can help me out with this since I am new to react-native and redux.

I want to populate a FlatList with just a name and I am using this classes (along with others obviously):

actions.js

```
const LOAD_CLIENT = 'LOAD_CLIENT';

export async function loadClient() {
  const client = await Parse.Query("Client");
  return {
    type: LOAD_CLIENT,
    client: client,
  };
}
```

reducers.js

```
import { LOAD_CLIENT } from '../actions'

const initialState = {
  objectId: null,
  name: null,
};

function client(state: State = initialState, action: Action): State {
  if (action.type === LOAD_CLIENT) {
    let {objectId, name} = action.client; // de-structuring action data
    return {
      objectId,
      name,
    };
  }

  return state;
}

module.exports = client;
```

listScreen.js

```
import {
  loadClient
} from './actions'

class SettingsScreen extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <FlatList style={styles.listStyle}
              data={this.props.client}
              renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
              />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default SettingsScreen
```

What do I need to be able to populate the list with client.name?
I followed Redux basics to get here but now I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Please change something like this in your file.

reducer.js

```
import { LOAD_CLIENT } from '../actions'

const initialState = {
    data: null,
};

function client(state: State = initialState, action: Action): State {
    if (action.type === LOAD_CLIENT) {
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            data: action.client
        });
    }
    return state;
}

module.exports = client;
```

listScreen.js

```
import { loadClient } from './actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class SettingsScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            client: null,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.loadClientData();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.data != null) {
            this.setState({
                client: nextProps.data
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <FlatList style={styles.listStyle}
              data={this.state.client}
              renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
              />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.reducers.data
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    loadClientData: () => dispatch(loadClient())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SettingsScreen)
```

or you can refer to this link for your practice.

https://medium.com/@imranhishaam/advanced-redux-with-react-native-b6e95a686234

Comment: Thanks for the pointing me in the right direction although it did not fix my  problem.

Comment: @Estevex you can refer the link, which is posted on my answer. So you can get the exact point about the Redux, Reducers.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to connect your component.

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux;
 {...}
const mapStateToProps = ({reducerName})=>{
    const {name, objectId} = reducerName;
return {name, objectId}
}
```

after this name and objectId will be available on component props.
But remember that the flatList data needs an array so your reducer should have a variable clients:[] that will populate on fetch with all the data.
Flatlist wont work if u pass only an object, you need to pass an array of objects